# iOS app needs to access a p12 certificate

Tags: download, ios8, certificate

I am trying to develop an iOS application that requires downloading a .p12 certificate.

I am fairly new to this and would like some guidance as to how to accomplish this.

Appreciate your help, Thanks!

Comment: For which feature you need this certificate.

Comment: iOS Clients communicate with an authentication server that requires the clients to present their identities when the authentication challenge is issued. I want to app to download a p12 certificate from a web server and present it when needed. I see that there is documentation on how to extract the p12 - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html. But my question is can we download it and save it (if so, where?) and use it when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the iPhone developer certificate to a P12 file on Mac OS
Once you have downloaded the Apple iPhone certificate from Apple, export it to the P12 certificate format. To do this on Mac® OS:

1. Open the Keychain Access application (in the Applications/Utilities
   folder).
2. If you have not already added the certificate to Keychain, select
   File > Import (Under "System"). Then navigate to the certificate file (the .cer file)
   you obtained from Apple.
3. Select the Keys category in Keychain Access.
4. Select the private key associated with your iPhone Development
   Certificate.
5. The private key is identified by the iPhone Developer: 
    public certificate that is paired with it.
6. Select File > Export Items.
7. Save your key in the Personal Information Exchange (.p12) file
   format.